# How to integrate Dropbox with Wingpanel?

Tags: applications, wingpanel

I would like to have an icon for Dropbox in Wingpanel (preferably one that matches the style of the default icons there) and have it display the current status (updated, synchronizing, offline).

What's the best/easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: I believe this should be made into two separate questions. I can answer the part about `Wingpanel`, but I don't know how to integrate the app with `Files`.

Comment: @Gabriel I believe Dropbox integration is a single issue, conceptually speaking. Besides, it's perfectly fine if you can only offer a partial answer -- that already helps :)

Comment: @Gabriel partial answers are fine if there are 2 parts to it :)

Comment: **Update:** I split the question in two, per http://meta.elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/6/84, and accepted the current answer. The second part was moved here: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/256/84

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To add the Dropbox icon to the Panel I used the script "Dropbox for elementary OS", available [here](https://github.com/zant95/elementary-dropbox).

### Instructions

This script, designed for elementary OS, installs the latest version of Dropbox and integrates it with WingPanel.

[image: System tray icon preview]

**Before you install**

You need to install `git` with:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

and uninstall any previous version of Dropbox on your system:

```
sudo apt-get remove dropbox*
```

**Install**

```
git clone https://github.com/zant95/elementary-dropbox /tmp/elementary-dropbox
bash /tmp/elementary-dropbox/install.sh
```

Dropbox will auto-update when a new version is available.

**Uninstall**

```
git clone https://github.com/zant95/elementary-dropbox /tmp/elementary-dropbox
bash /tmp/elementary-dropbox/uninstall.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does removing dropbox delete the files in it, or can I leave the directory for the script to reuse?

Comment: You mean if removing `Dropbox` will remove **your** personal files? Absolutely not, only the files pertaining to the app will be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It wasn't much of a concern, since the files would still live on dropbox.com and my other machines, but it would be wasteful to delete the files and then download them again once the script reinstalled dropbox.

Comment: @waldyrious your files will never be removed, but re-installing `Dropbox` means it will take it some time to re-index all your files. That's just a check to see if what's in their database matches what you have on your system, it will not have to download/upload all your files again.

Comment: I followed the above steps but the icon is not showing up in Wingpanel. Has anyone else had the same problem and knows a solution?

Comment: I have the same problem @orschiro

Comment: @Revod: Unfortunately, I cannot provide you with a solution. I switched to Ubuntu 15.04 in which the problem does not appear. It must be eOS-specific.

Comment: @orschiro I clean the cache of my computer, and try again the tutorial dowloading everything and work

Answer (score 9):

There's no point of running that script (that downloads Dropbox again, plus another time for the executable).

Just unset the dropbox application from the startup applications (Parameters=> Applications => Startup)
And then create a new startup application with these instructions

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE='' dropbox start
```

You will get a nice dropbox icon ! ;-)

**WATCH OUT** for the single quotes !

**ATTENTION**: To get the *legacy* indicators (like *Dropbox*) displayed, you will need to install [elementary-indicators](https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Works for me, Elementary OS Loki.

Comment: Works on Elementary OS Juno too

Comment: None of the two methods work for me on fresh Juno - I tried this first to no avail, then the github script and the icon still doesn't show up. Now what?

Comment: You need *elementary-indicators* as specified in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

elementary OS 5 Juno and later does not have a “system tray” or support app indicators, as this is a decade-deprecated API and has been replaced with more useful, purposeful APIs like CloudProviders. You can read about all of that in this [elementary blog post](https://medium.com/elementaryos/developer-tips-backgrounding-system-integration-31c1f7226606).

Since Dropbox is a proprietary app, only Dropbox themselves can update their app to support modern APIs that are used by desktops like elementary OS and GNOME. Alternatively, someone could apply for a developer API key and attempt to make an open source Dropbox front-end that integrates with these modern APIs.

Until one of those happens, there is no supported way to get better Dropbox integration into elementary OS.

Comment: The [HIG entry](https://elementary.io/docs/human-interface-guidelines#system-indicators) linked from that very blog post does not seem to disavow app indicators in the system tray, though. It explains when such an integration makes sense or not, and according to those recommendations, system-related information like those related to the filesystem (Dropbox, Google Drive), network (VPN, IPFS) and performance indicators should be acceptable.