# How to integrate Dropbox with the file manager (Files)?

Tags: applications, pantheon-files

When on Files, I'd like to be able to:

- see the little icon overlays in files and folders that indicate whether they're up to date or synchronizing
- when right-clicking on a file or folder inside the Dropbox folder, have the usual Dropbox items ("Get public link", "Open in dropbox.com", etc.) in the context menu

What's the best/easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: FYI, there's an open bug for this integration (both in the file manager and in the wingpanel), and it has [an associated bounty](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/3978067-missing-dropbox-integration) (currently $25) that anyone who solves this in elementary OS can claim :)

Answer (score 12):

The elementary OS daily PPA contains a Dropbox plugin for Pantheon, which seems a little bit outdated but still works fine.

**Please don't add elementary-daily-PPA to your sources, it is for testing purposes only and may break your system!**

Instead download the plugin and install it manually:
[pantheon-files-plugin-dropbox i386](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/daily/+files/pantheon-files-plugin-dropbox_0.1-0%7E22%7Esaucy1_i386.deb)
[pantheon-files-plugin-dropbox amd64](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/daily/+files/pantheon-files-plugin-dropbox_0.1-0%7E22%7Esaucy1_amd64.deb)

There is a small bug in this package, but luckily we can fix it. 
After you installed `pantheon-files-plugin`, start pantheon in the terminal:

```
pantheon-files
```

now take a closer look at the output in the terminal. If you see this error message:

```
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 23:17:33.808365] PluginManager.vala:128: Failed to load module from path '/usr/lib/pantheon-files/plugins/libmarlin-dropbox.so': libmarlincore.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

close all instances of `pantheon files` and run this command in the terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libpantheon-files-core.so.0 /usr/lib/libmarlincore.so.0
```

Run `pantheon-files` in the terminal again, the error message must be gone now.

Unfortunately the default elementary OS icon theme doesn't provide the necessary emblem icons. I've created some of my own and pushed them to [elementary+](https://github.com/mank319/elementaryPlus). After you installed this icon theme (just follow the instructions on their GitHub page), you should see nice overlay icons and have a right click context-menu in your Dropbox folder:

[image]

Comment: I followed these instructions (installed both the .deb and `elementaryplus` from the PPA as instructed in Github) and I still don't see any icons. Perhaps a restart or log out/in is necessary?

Comment: @Gabriel maybe it is necessary...

Comment: The use of elementary Tweaks is discouraged both by the devs and the creator (who is not maintaining it anymore) It'd be better if you could instruct on how to select the icon set without having to use that app.

Comment: Um, this doesn't seem t work for me on Luna. The elementary+ PPA doesn't seem to support it: `E: Unable to locate package elementaryplus`. Also, given what @Gabriel said here in the comments, is this still something I should do? Is there any other way?

Comment: @waldyrious elementary+ only supports the current stable version Freya, I'm sorry :(

Comment: @Gabriel I totally forgot about a small bug in the plugin-package. There is now a bugfix in my answer, please try it and tell me, if it works...

Comment: @waldyrious I try to find a suitable solution for Luna users, hang on. BTW: I added a small bugfix to my answer, but I don't know if it must be applied in Luna.

Comment: Does it stopped working?

Comment: just installed on Juno, works good, without elementaryplus

Answer (score 0):

## Juno

In Juno you install the integration plugin with:

```
sudo apt install pantheon-files-plugin-dropbox
```

This plugin was written by an elementary dev Cody Garver and it's in the official elementary PPA (already included in default software sources). Works pretty well, I got emblems as well as the right-click menu. No indicator or similar status-checking thingy though. It also doesn't pull Dropbox, so you still need `nautilus-dropbox` to install Dropbox itself (see `apt show pantheon-files-plugin-dropbox`)

Comment: this solution got broken couple of weeks ago, so it no longer works :/

Answer (score -1):

The above solution (with the plugin and elementary+) does not work for Loki.
The `libmarlin-dropbox.so` file is not even copied to `/usr/lib`.

You could also install Caja Dropbox that seems better integrated (but that would mean using caja instead of files).

It can be done :

- either from the command line `sudo apt install caja-dropbox caja`
- or from the Application Center

Comment: Thanks for the info, but note that this answer has the exact same problem as the one by @pawel.ad: it doesn't fit the question's requirement of integrating into Files. The suggestion here is fine as a workaround, so it will certainly be useful to others, but it does not answer the original question.

Answer (score -6):

One option I used a while back is to switch from `pantheon-files` to `nautilus` (and its `nautilus-dropbox`), which should be avalible by default in your repositories.

Comment: I don't think that this is the proper answer since he specifically said Files in the body of the question.